# BigRock Hosting error: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, shared-hosting

My application works perfectly on my local machine. But when I tried to publish it on BigRock Shared Hosting I get following error message-

**Security Exception**

> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

**Stack Trace:**

> [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
>      System.Delegate.DelegateConstruct(Object target, IntPtr slot) +0
>      Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader..ctor(Func`3 next, Func`2 activator, IEnumerable`1 referencedAssemblies) +69
>      Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup() +65
>      Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +28
>      System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
>      Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +106
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +418
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>      System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

How can I resolve this?

Comment: this seems like it's probably something you need to take up with your hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

An error indicates that either your website is not running under its own application pool Or your website requires the trust level that your web host don't allow. For instance, your application requires Full trust level to run and your web host don't allow to run applications under Full trust level.